# ActiveX controls changing to pictures (Excel/VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, activex

My company creates workbooks for clients that contain ActiveX controls (in most cases we need the extra functionality as compared to Form Controls).  When we create them, they work fine on our end, but when we zip them up and send them to our clients, they open the WB and the ActiveX controls are no longer ActiveX controls, if you right click it, it behaves like a picture.

I feel like this is due to the MS ActiveX debacle.  I have had them run the Fix It and making sure all the MS Office components were closed, and had them reboot, but still nothing.

I am pulling out my hair, and have asked on other forums if anyone else has had this issue, and what they have done to fix it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you right click, and you see "Assign Macro", that sounds like a forms button. Is this what's happening?

Comment: This one maybe: http://kb-links.com/2009/microsoft/2000253/  Sorry about not linking to MS directly - for some reason they now insist on signing in to see KB articles (and "we can't sign you in right now. Please try again later.")

Comment: @Davesexcel - No, sadly.  Its not a form, its a picture.  I teach my team to right click and look for "properties" to make sure its an activex control.  When I right click the items in question it brings up "Format Picture"

Comment: @TimWilliams - These were created in Excel 2007, so a bulb went off, BUT none of these clients use 2003, so back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check in client system whether macros and active x controls are enabled in Trust center setting?

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-documents-7b4fdd2e-174f-47e2-9611-9efe4f860b12?CorrelationId=fe6a4d24-f4d9-4c6b-afa0-40d2828ad22e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

use above link if needed.

Comment: @Negendra - That is the first thing I checked out.   The Trust settings are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing excel and deleting the .EXD files from your computer.

Source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/296750-command-button-turned-into-image.html

Answer (score 0):

While saving the Excel document, save it as "Macro enabled workbook".xlsm

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the worksheet prompts a non responsive error sometimes.  When I reopen it, Excel repairs it and turns all active X check boxes (sometimes drop down list and command buttons) into images.  It happened many times and I had to spend a lot of my time recreating them and liking to cells.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem when Excel repaired a file; this may be similar to what's happening with the Zipped file.  FormControl Buttons don't appear to have the same problems but I see you want to keep the additional functionality of the ActiveX Control.

You may be able to make use of the code I created by inserting one Form Control button that runs the **Sub RepairMissingButtons()** that your clients can press to restore the images to CommandButtons. This currently fixes buttons for any selected sheets, so you'd want to first identify which sheets need to be selected (or add a form control button on each sheet that needs the repair done).

You'd need to modify the **Sub CreateButton()** to meet your needs (currently requires hard-coding the Caption, BackColor and any other ActiveX properties that may have been lost by the button being converted to an image):

[Reverse Excel ActiveX command buttons erroneously converted to images after corrupted file repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205940/how-to-use-vba-to-reverse-excel-activex-command-buttons-erroneously-converted-to)

Answer (score 0):

Having this problem, activex controls sometimes change to pictures.

Many places around the internet the answer is: Use form controls, well as far as I can tell form controls don't actually do anything useful.

Even Microsoft's support site says, recommend using form controls, how can that be the answer. being able to interact with VBA is as far as I can tell the only reason to use Microsoft applications instead of free ones.